# Groovy problem (package keyword seen as invalid token) with test using archetype generated by maven

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, maven

I'm trying to launch the tests of the groovy simple archetype generated by maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate 
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.gmaven.archetypes
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=gmaven-archetype-basic -DarchetypeVersion=1.3
```

But when I launch the ExampleTest.groovy in `src/test/groovy/fr/xlim/ssd/fuzzer/ExampleTest.groovy`:

```
import Example

package fr.xlim.ssd.fuzzer

class ExampleTest extends GroovyTestCase
{
  void testShow() {
    assert true
    new Example().show()
  }
}
```

I've the following error:

```
unexpected token: package - file:/home/kartoch/works/groovy/fuzzer
/src/test/groovy/fr/xlim/ssd/fuzzer/ExampleTest.groovy[3:1]
```

It seems the package keyword is badly placed or not recognized by the groovy compiler, even if the test file is in the correct directory.

Any ideas ? maybe a syntax changes in Groovy (I'm using groovy 1.7) ?

**Note:** this error may not be related to maven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your import under the package line, just as in Java.